# How to insert stanza in middle of the file using chef cookbooks

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to insert a stanza in middle of the file. 
Would like to achieve this using chef cookbook.

This is how I do it on bash script. Any suggestions on how to handle this in chef?

Basically would like to add a vendor specific stanza to /etc/multipath.conf file after installing the package.

**example:**

```
# cat current.txt
a
b
c
# cat new.txt
11
12
13
# sed -i '/^a/ r new.txt' current.txt
# cat current.txt
a
11
12
13
b
c
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Actual answer, using the `line` or `poise-file` cookbooks (or rather with the custom resources included in those cookbooks).

Real answer, please don't do this is you can possibly help it. It leads to very brittle code since the file might change in ways you don't expect so suddenly your delta update assertions fail somehow, usually silently. If at all possible, have Chef manage the whole content of the file, usually via a `template` resource, since that can be done convergently.

Comment: Thanks @coderanger. Will look in to the cookbooks suggested. I don't have control on the complete file, I am afraid managing the whole content of the file from chef may not be possible.